# Naming setter parameters in PHP

Tags: php, coding-style

I hesitate between using the name of the current setter versus using a common name (such as $value) for all setters.

```
// Style 1
function set_section($section);

// Style 2
function set_section($value);
```

Comment: Well, what value does the parameter represent?

Comment: @Gumbo: It's a value that is going to be passed to a private member with the same name as the name of the setter. Here's what the whole function would look like: function set_section($value) { $this->section = $value }

Comment: @Emanuil: But what kind of value does this *section* represent? Is it a section’s name/number/etc. or some kind of section itself?

Comment: I think both ways are essentially fine. If you are using a framework, I'd stick to their convention.

Comment: @Gumbo: That's great question. In this case it's the section name. I guess $name is another good candidate for the parameter name.

Comment: @Emanuil: That was what I was aiming for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name it what the parameter value represents. If it’s a section name, use *name* or *section name*; if it’s a section number, use *number* or *section number*; if it’s some kind of section itself, call it *section*.

Comment: I guess I'll have to change the setter function name to "set_section_name". Then the function definition would look like - function set_section_name($section_name).

Comment: @Emanuil: You don’t need that redundancy. If your method name does also specify the entity the method is called on, you can omit it in the parameter name. So I would just use `set_section_name($name)`. But if you have a method that has multiple entities that need to be distinguished between, use more verbose names like in `set_names($section_name, $subsection_name)`. But again, this does all depend on what entity `set_section_name` is called on.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with `value` since it's the same name that is being used in .NET.